# How to change the java code on runtime by MethodInterceptor

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, interceptor

I want to modify my code on runtime by @annotation and interceptor. I created a simple example to explain my need on the stackoverflow website.

How to change `i = i + 1;` to `i = i + 3;` on runtime (in my `invoke` of `MyRetryInterceptor`).

My original (public) code:

```
@MyRetry(value = 3)
public void testforRetry() {
    int i = 0;
    logger.info("testforRetry " + i);
    i = i + 1;
    logger.info("testforRetry " + i);
}
```

My Method Interceptor:

```
public class MyRetryInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Method m = invocation.getMethod();
        Object result = invocation.proceed();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I can use ASM if you want.

Comment: @StackFlowed, you marked as duplicate but have you an example with AspectJ please ?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, you marked as duplicate but have you an example with AspectJ please ?